# Using a variable to reference and modifying a querySelector

Tags: javascript

Is there a way for me to use a variable to reference and modifying a querySelector? I have tried a few time but it hasn't worked out.

Here is an example of from my code:

```js
var detailPanelTitle = document.querySelector('span[class^="title-"]');

if (detailPanelTitle !== null) {    
  var detailPanelTitleText = detailPanelTitle.innerHTML;
  // Modify my title
  document.querySelector('span[class^="title-"]').innerHTML = detailPanelTitleText + ": this is my title";
}
```

This is what I would like to do:

```js
var detailPanelTitle = document.querySelector('span[class^="title-"]');

if (detailPanelTitle !== null) {    
  var detailPanelTitleText = detailPanelTitle.innerHTML;
  // Modify my title
  detailPanelTitleText = detailPanelTitleText + ": this is my title";
}
```

Is there a way to point to the innerHTML object with a variable and edit it later?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can write `detailPanelTitle.innerHTML = detailPanelTitleText + "whatever"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to distinguish the object from the text.

```js
var detailPanelTitleObj = document.querySelector('span[class^="title-"]');

if (detailPanelTitleObj !== null) {    
  var detailPanelTitleText = detailPanelTitleObj.innerText;
  // Modify my title
  detailPanelTitleObj.innerText = detailPanelTitleText + ": this is my title";
}
```

Comment: But you have to work the last part because html is not pure text.        

    detailPanelTitleObj = detailPanelTitleText + ": this is my title";

Comment: You can use the detailPanelTitleObj.innerText = "new text"

Answer (score 0):

```
detailPanelTitle.innerHTML += ": this is my title";
```

The issue on your example is that you are setting the value of you local variable `detailPanelTitleText` instead of reusing `detailPanelTitle` and setting it's field `innerHTML`.

```
detailPanelTitleText = detailPanelTitleText + ": this is my title";
```

Comment: Is there to way to point directly to the field and re-use it multiple times?

Comment: No. You must always reference `innerHTML` from the span instance. But the span instance does not have to be held in a local variable. You can keep it in a wider scope. You could make a function called `SetDetailPanelTitleText()` that accepts a string and assigns it to the span's innerHTML or innerText.